# Play 2 connections issue when trying to access remote db from cloudbees

Tags: playframework-2.0, cloudbees

Sometimes my play2 app is working but sometimes not. I suspect it is not releasing connections in dev mode. This is the error:

```
    [error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to obtain initial connection Sle
eping for 0ms and trying again. Attempts left: 0. Exception: null
[error] application -

! @6c1j5m094 - Internal server error, for request [GET /] ->

play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error [Cannot connect to database
[default]]
        at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configura
tion.scala:71) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
        at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:258) ~[play_2.
9.1.jar:2.0.4]
        at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:249) ~[pla
y_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
        at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:240) ~[pla
y_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike
.scala:194) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike
.scala:194) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: User bestt
v already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections
```

This is my configuration (I put only the entries I added to solve this but seems to not help):

```
db.default.partitionCount=1
db.default.maxConnectionsPerPartition=5
db.default.minConnectionsPerPartition=1
db.default.acquireIncrement=1
db.default.acquireRetryAttempts=1
db.default.acquireRetryDelay=5 seconds
```

I don't understand if it's related to cloudbees or play. Something similar play guys said it's resolved in play 2 (in January) but seems not..

Comment: Would you be able to post your app somewhere? Or a sample app that does this. I'm having trouble reproducing this on default config. Are you using ebean?

Comment: I'm too getting this error, did you find the solution for this?